# Is D member function std.process.environment.toAA buggy?

Tags: thread-safety, environment-variables, d

From `/snap/dlang/43/usr/include/dlang/dmd/std/process.d`:

```
string[string] toAA() @trusted
{
    import std.conv : to;
    string[string] aa;
    version (Posix)
    {
        auto environ = getEnvironPtr;
        for (int i=0; environ[i] != null; ++i)
        {
            import std.string : indexOf;

            immutable varDef = to!string(environ[i]);
            immutable eq = indexOf(varDef, '=');
            assert(eq >= 0);

            immutable name = varDef[0 .. eq];
            immutable value = varDef[eq+1 .. $];

            // In POSIX, environment variables may be defined more
            // than once.  This is a security issue, which we avoid
            // by checking whether the key already exists in the array.
            // For more info:
            // http://www.dwheeler.com/secure-programs/Secure-Programs-HOWTO/environment-variables.html
            if (name !in aa)  aa[name] = value;
        }
    }
    // ...
}
```

But `getEnvironPtr()` is defined as follows:

```
extern(C) extern __gshared const char** environ;
const(char**) getEnvironPtr() @trusted
{
    return environ;
}
```

The above code seems for me beign not thread safe because of use `__gshared` and the fact that `environ` extern variable is modifyable. Is this a bug in D? Or what may I misunderstand?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is the only way to do it in Posix. The variable is marked const, so you can't modify it, but you can declare another extern(C) variable that can modify the same memory. So don't do that.

D does a lot to make things safe, but the only way to make this truly safe would be to eliminate extern(C). Or to get rid of Posix and rebuild an OS from scratch in D. Those are both drastic measures disproportionate to the size of the problem.